# How can I pipe a rack file upload directly to S3?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rack

Is it possible to pipe a file upload using ruby?

Instead of reading the whole file into memory, or writing a temp file to then write to S3, I was hoping to stream the request body directly.

[Streaming data to S3 with ruby](http://journal.missiondata.com/post/63407233782/streaming-data-to-s3-with-ruby) shows how to stream to S3, but I'm not sure how to turn the request body in a rack app into a readable stream.

```
class FastUploadApp
  def self.call(env)
    # what goes here?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right that you need to turn the request body into a readable stream. Specifically, S3 expects a Ruby IO class (in that it wants a #read method and a #eof? method). Rack request bodies don't have #eof? defined, however, so you have to make a little wrapper class:

```
class RackS3Wrapper
  def initialize(body)
    @body = body
    @eof = false
  end

  def read(*args)
    ret = @body.read(*args)

    if ret == nil or ret == ""
      @eof = true
    end

    ret
  end

  def eof?
    @eof
  end
end
```

Then you can use this wrapper to stream the request to S3 directly:

```
s3.buckets['com.mydomain.mybucket'].objects['filename'].write(
  :data => RackS3Wrapper.new(request.body), 
  :content_length => request.env['CONTENT_LENGTH'].to_i)
```

This hasn't been tested in production or anything, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my project middl: https://github.com/diclophis/middl

It has some caveats ... mostly you have to rely on the client sending an appropriate request size header (which is not required by the w3 spec)